# Ошибка с выводом-вводом

Tags: c++

Есть такой кусок кода. Проблема в том, что когда выводится "ФИО: ", то он почему-то переходит на новую строку. Как это пофиксить?

```
listStudents* newStudent = new listStudents;
system("cls");
std::cout << "ФИО: ";
std::cin >> newStudent->student.name;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут вроде такая же проблемка описана:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/223414/
поведение самой IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевот ответа по ссылке @mangusta

Нет, это поведение появляется от процессов `cmd.exe` и `conhost.exe`. Нет варианта решения. Если запустить этот код на linux то я получаю (пример адаптирован под вашу проблему)

```
ФИО: linuxuser@linux:~$
```

Зачем это нужно, по моему мнению программа отправляя вывод в `stdout` должна отправлять перенос строки как последний символ не зависимо от платформы, за исключением разных причин не делать это.

---

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/223414/#msg1023756

<sup>Переведенный текст не является моим мнением</sup>